# Is it quicker to search a column or an array in excel vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, search

I have a large column of id's I need to search.  Is it quicker to search the column, or load the column into an array and then search the array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want done exactly.
Why don't you time it and see for yourself like:

```
Sub CheckPerformance()
    Dim start

    start = Timer
    ' Code that uses searching like looping, or Range Find Method goes here
    Debug.Print (Timer - start) * 1000 ' elapse time in milliseconds

    start = Timer
    ' Code that passes values to array and loops goes here
    Debug.Print (Timer - start) * 1000 ' elapse time in milliseconds

End Sub
```

You'll find your answer then.